# how to check if a string is palindrome using stack in c#

Tags: c#

hi i am trying to check if a string is palindrome or not using stack in c#. i have entered string into a stack and reversed it. the problem is in checking these both.how to check or compare each character in stack.

```
namespace Pallindrome
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Stack Palindrome = new Stack();
        public static Stack palindrome1 = new Stack();
        public static string text;
        public static string text2 = palindrome1.ToString();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the string:");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            var text1 = text.ToUpper();
            BuildWordStack(text);
            ReverseWord();
            palindromecheck(text,text2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void BuildWordStack(string text1)
        {
            int n = text1.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Palindrome.Push(text1.ElementAt(i));
            }
            foreach (var item in Palindrome)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            var counti = Palindrome.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("The length is {0}", counti);
        }

        public static void ReverseWord()
        {
            int w = Palindrome.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                palindrome1.Push(Palindrome.Pop());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Reversed");
            foreach (var item in palindrome1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            char[] temp = text.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {

            }

            foreach (var item in temp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
        public static void palindromecheck(string enter, string check)
        {
            if (enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's a palindrome");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's not a palindrome");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i expect the output to be palindrome if the string is palindrome or not palindrome if the string is not palindrome. but in my program it shows not a palindrome for every string

Comment: Please describe where is your *specific* issue. What does not work? Where is the error? What is the piece of code you are not sure about?

Comment: Think about what happens if you push 1, 2, 3 onto a stack, then pop those values onto another stack and pop them off the second stack. (Hint: 123 => 321 =>123)

Comment: I don't think you should reverse the string and compare with the original when told to "check palindrome _with a stack_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Stack palindrome;
public static Stack palindromeReverse;
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the string:");
    var text = Console.ReadLine();
    BuildWordStack(text);
    PalindromeCheck(text, ReverseWord());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
public static void BuildWordStack(string word)
{
    palindrome = new Stack();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Count(); i++)
    {
        palindrome.Push(word.ElementAt(i));
    }
}

public static string ReverseWord()
{
    palindromeReverse = new Stack();
    int n = palindrome.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        palindromeReverse.Push(palindrome.Pop());
    }
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result = palindromeReverse.Pop() + result;
    }
    return result;
}
public static void PalindromeCheck(string word, string reverse)
{
    if (word.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper() == reverse.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: hi,the question for the program is below... can you please check it

Comment: Write a Console application that obtains a word from the user and 
using at least one stack , appropriate static variables and the static methods listed below, you are to determine whether the word is a palindrome or not.  Then display the appropriate response back to the screen.

Comment: • BuildWordStack()
This method receives the word entered by the user as a parameter and has the job of pushing the characters of that word onto a stack.
• ReverseWord()
This method receives no parameters but has the job of returning a string; the word (the characters from the stack) in reverse.
• PalindromeCheck()
This method receives two parameters (the word entered, and the word in reverse) and has the job of comparing them, and displaying an appropriate message, stating if the word is a palindrome or not.The program should ignore capitalization and spaces.

Comment: modified answer